# Reading binary stream until "\r\n" is encountered

Tags: java, http, bufferedreader, mjpeg

I'm working on a Java application which will stream video from an IP Camera. The video streams from the IP Camera in MJPEG format. The protocol is the following...

```
--ipcamera (\r\n)
Content-Type: image/jpeg (\r\n)
Content-Length: {length of frame} (\r\n)
(\r\n)
{frame}
(\r\n)
--ipcamera (\r\n)
etc.
```

I've tried using classes such as BufferedReader and Scanner to read until the "\r\n", however those are meant for text and not binary data, so it becomes corrupt. Is there any way to read the binary stream until it encounters a "\r\n"? Here is my current (broken) code.

EDIT: I've gotten it to work. I updated the code below. However, it's really slow in doing so. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the ArrayList or not, but it could be the culprit. Any pointers to speed up the code? It's currently taking 500ms to 900ms for a single frame.

```
public void run() {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    try {
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        urlConn.connect();
        urlStream = urlConn.getInputStream();
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(urlStream);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ArrayList<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
        byte cur;
        int curi;
        byte[] curBytes;
        int length = 0;
        while ((curi = dis.read()) != -1) {
            cur = (byte) curi;
            bytes.add(cur);
            curBytes = getPrimativeArray(bytes);
            String curBytesString = new String(curBytes, "UTF-8");
            if (curBytesString.equals("--ipcamera\r\n")) {
                bytes.clear();
                continue;
            } else if (curBytesString.equals("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n")) {
                bytes.clear();
                continue;
            } else if (curBytesString.matches("^Content-Length: ([0-9]+)\r\n$")) {
                length = Integer.parseInt(curBytesString.replace("Content-Length: ", "").trim());
                bytes.clear();
                continue;
            } else if (curBytesString.equals("\r\n")) {
                if (length == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                byte[] frame = new byte[length];
                dis.readFully(frame, 0, length);
                writeFrame(frame);
                bytes.clear();
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    System.out.println(curTime);
}

private byte[] getPrimativeArray(ArrayList<Byte> array) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[array.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        bytes[i] = array.get(i).byteValue();
    }
    return bytes;
}

private void writeFrame(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("C:\\test.jpg");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.close();
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently you do not cope with the case when data is read in the frame part.

A rough assumption is:

**Current version:**

```
else if (line.equals("") && length != 0)
```

**Probably more correct version:**

```
else if (!line.equals("") && length != 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use BufferedReader to read binary, it will corrupt it.  I you want to keep things simple, use DataInputStream.readLine().  Though not ideal, it may be the simplest in your case.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize that BufferedReader was only for text. It makes sense considering it returns a char[], lol. Is there any other way to read until "\r\n" is found? I'd prefer not to use readLine() in DataInputStream since it's deprecated. I've tried using the Scanner class, but it's like BufferedReader and is meant for text.

Comment: DataInputStream.readLine() is deprecated because it reads text, but assume an ISO-8859-1 encoding which I suspect is ok in your case.  You can write you own readLine() method but I think it will end up doing the same thing.  Sometimes the simplest choice is a deprecated method.

Comment: I've got it working with an ArrayList<Byte> reading the headers, then reading the rest into a byte[] after it gets the length and finds the "\r\n". However, it's really slow (500ms-900ms). Any pointers?

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList<Byte>` it is really, really slow.  You can use BufferedInputStream to help if you haven't done this already.

Answer (score 2):

Other than using some bad practices and assuming that your `URLConnection` correctly delivers the data, the example you posted seems to work if you reset the length to zero after reading the frame data.

```
} else if (line.equals("") && length != 0) {
    char[] buf = new char[length];
    reader.read(buf, 0, length);
    baos.write(new String(buf).getBytes());
    //break;
    length = 0;  // <-- reset length
}
```

Please note this way all the frame data are written in the same `ByteArrayOutputStream` consecutively. If you don't want that, you should create a new `ByteArrayOutputStream` for every new frame you encounter.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't use a `BufferedReader` for part of the transmission and then some other stream for the rest of it. The `BufferedReader` will fill its buffer and steal some of the data you want to read with the other stream. Use `DataInputStream.readLine(),` noting that it's deprecated, or else roll your own line-reading code, using the input stream provided by the `URLConnection.`
2. Surely you don't have to? `URLConnection` reads the headers for you. If you want the content-length, use the API to get it. The stuff you get to read starts at the body of the transmission.

Comment: The headers aren't HTTP Headers, they're MJPEG separators which separate each individual JPEG image.